# Convert list of IP into fixed CIDR form

Tags: bash, networking, ipv4

Is there a tool that we can convert a list of IP into a fixed network CIDR form with `x.x.x.0/24` and `x.x.0.0/16`? For example, to demonstrate this, I have list of IPs that possibly can be converted to these fixed form like below:

First if I want to convert list of IP below to possible CIDR 24 but with fixed form of `x.x.x.0/24`:

`./list2cidr 24 iplist.txt`

```
1.22.3.4
1.28.3.5
1.211.3.7
1.211.3.2
1.211.3.1

Output:

1.22.3.4
1.28.3.5
1.211.3.0/24
```

How does it work?

First, it scans through the list of IP with the same network which it looks at the 3rd octet if they are in the same network, we combine it to become `x.x.x.0/24`. In this case, there are 3 IPs with the same network in the 3rd octect:

```
1.211.3.7
1.211.3.2
1.211.3.1
```

So this would be: `1.211.3.0/24`

Another example, if I want to convert list of IP below to possible CIDR 16 with fixed form of `x.x.0.0/16`:

`./list2cidr 16 iplist.txt`

```
1.1.4.1
1.1.4.2
1.22.44.1
1.22.3.2
1.22.1.9

Output:

1.1.0.0/16
1.22.0.0/16
```

When I passed the argument that contains `16` it will look at the 2nd octet if they are in the same network, so we combine it to become `x.x.0.0/16`

Should I start writing a script for this or is there a tool that exists for this purpose?

EDIT:

I'm interested to make the CIDR form looks like one of these: `1.1.1.0/24` and `1.1.0.0/16`. So, `1.1.0.0/24` or `1.1.1.0/16` are not what I want.

That means, if pass `list2cidr 24 iplist.txt`, it must form this output

`x.x.x.0/24`

and if I pass `list2cidr 16 iplist.txt`, it must form this output

`x.x.0.0/16`

Currently, I have done the first part of the output using bash script but I have not fully tested it yet

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/671839/edit) to include more detail, specifically why the second example would not be: `1.1.0.0/16` `1.22.0.0/16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know one, so I wrote one (in perl).  I also figured your tool design was incomplete.

- It should only give CIDR blocks of the requested levels, even when there is only one address therein.
- It should also work without a target level.

Thus:

```
$ cat sample

1.22.3.4
1.28.3.5
1.211.3.7
1.211.3.2
1.211.3.1

$ list2cidr 24 sample

1.22.3.0/24
1.28.3.0/24
1.211.3.0/24

$ list2cidr 16 sample

1.22.0.0/16
1.28.0.0/16
1.211.0.0/16

$ list2cidr sample

1.0.0.0/8
    1.16.0.0/12
        1.22.3.4
        1.28.3.5
    1.211.3.0/29
        1.211.3.0/30
            1.211.3.1
            1.211.3.2
        1.211.3.7

$
```

My current implementation only does IPv4.  The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $target;
if ($ARGV[0] =~ m{^\d+}) {
    $target = + shift @ARGV;
}


my $map = [];

sub record($) 
{
    my $v = shift;

    my $m = $map;
    for my $i ( 0 .. 31 ) {
        my $k = $v & (1 << (31-$i));
        $m = $m->[!!$k] ||= (($i == 31) ? $v : []);
    }
}

while (<>) {
    chomp;

    if (m{^\s*(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\s*\z}) {
        if (($1 < 256) && ($2 < 256) && ($3 < 256) && ($4 < 256)) {
            record(($1<<24) | ($2<<16) | ($3 << 8) | $4);
            next;
        }
    }

    printf("Invalid: %s\n", $_);
}

sub output($$$) {
    my ($addr, $bits, $indent) = @_;
    printf "%*s%d.%d.%d.%d",
           $indent*4, '',
           0xff & ($addr >> 24),
           0xff & ($addr >> 16),
           0xff & ($addr >>  8),
           0xff & ($addr      );
    printf("/%d", $bits) if $bits < 32;
    print "\n";
}

sub walk($$$$);
sub walk($$$$) {
    my ($prefix, $bits, $indent, $m) = @_;
    #printf ("%d %d %d ...\n", $prefix, $bits, $indent);
    if ($bits == ($target//-1)) {
        output $prefix<<(32-$bits), $bits, 0;
    } elsif ($bits == 32) { 
        warn 'mismatch '.$prefix.' != '.$m unless $prefix == $m;
        output $prefix, $bits, $indent unless defined $target;
    } elsif (defined $m->[0]) {
        if (defined $m->[1]) {
            output $prefix<<(32-$bits), $bits, $indent unless defined $target;
            walk($prefix*2,   $bits+1, $indent+1, $m->[0]);
            walk($prefix*2+1, $bits+1, $indent+1, $m->[1]);
        } else {
            walk($prefix*2,   $bits+1, $indent, $m->[0]);
        }
    } else {
        if (defined $m->[1]) {
            walk($prefix*2+1, $bits+1, $indent, $m->[1]);
        } else {
            warn sprintf('Empty node at prefix=%x bits=%d indent=%d', $prefix, $bits, $indent);
        }
    }
}

walk (0, 0, 0, $map);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this script does not meet the requirement as the first output. I'm interested to make the CIDR form looks like one of these: `1.1.1.0/24` and `1.1.0.0/16` So, `1.1.0.0/24` is not what I want. Currently I have done the first part of the output using bash script but I have not fully tested yet..

Comment: Sorry.  I had a bug in calling function `record` that caused the third byte to be 0 and the fourth to sometimes have 1 added.  This is now fixed.

Comment: Ok I tried this, I think this script explains what I want. I want to share my bounty with you. So, it would be 2 days you will receive it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I actually prefer to use bash script for this. I will try to understand your implementation because Im not familar with perl

Comment: The design was to build a tree, and then carefully print the significant nodes.  To understand the data, try adding at the end: `use Data::Dumper; print Data::Dumper->Dump([$map],['map']);`

Comment: Thanks, it is a matter of syntax that I'm not yet familiar with.  I never studied Perl. I will try to understand this

Comment: Why does `1.22.3.4` get left unchanged rather than being rewritten as `1.22.3.0/24`? If it's about having multiple addresses in the same subnet, how many need to be found in order for them to be coalesced?

Comment: Because `1.22.3.4` is alone, it doesn't have matching network group when inspecting the 3rd octet.

Comment: @ToiletGuy would 1.22.3.4 and 1.22.3.99 get coalesced to 1.22.3.0/24?

Comment: @roaima yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

The following uses the command-line utility `ipcalc` (from https://github.com/pyr/ipcalc) to calculate the network address for each address given in the file called `file` given the network mask `$mask`.

```bsh
xargs -I {} ipcalc {} / "$mask" <file |
awk -F: '$1 ~ /^network/ && !seen[$2]++ { gsub(" ","",$2); print $2 }'
```

In the end, `awk` parses the `ipcalc` output and extracts the unique network addresses.

Given your example data, running this with `mask=24` gives

```
1.22.3.0/24
1.28.3.0/24
1.211.3.0/24
```

With `mask=12`:

```
1.16.0.0/12
1.208.0.0/12
```

Modifying this slightly to allow us to use `ipcalc` from the `ipcalc` package on Ubuntu:

```bsh
xargs -I {} ipcalc -b {}/"$mask" <file |
awk -F: '$1 ~ /^Network/ && !seen[$2]++ { gsub(" ","",$2); print $2 }'
```

Comment: Thanks, currently I'm using ipcalc from here: `https://gitlab.com/ipcalc/ipcalc`. I guess, this going to have conflict with my ipcalc because my current ipcalc supports ipv6. Anyway I'll try what you suggested.